# json.loads() not converting into dict

Tags: python, json

I am having trouble with parsing a specific key from a json string in a table. Below is my code to read a csv file and extract "employee_id" from the json column in each row:

```
with open('data.csv') as csvFile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader, None)  # skips the header row

for row in csv_reader:
    event_data = row[4]
    data = json.loads(event_data)
    print(data['employee_id'])
```

Here is a sample event_data output:

```
"{\"py/object\": \"employee_information.event_types.EmployeeCreated\", \"employee_id\": \"98765\", \"employee_first_name\": \"Jonathan\", \"employee_last_name\": \"Smith\", \"application_id\": \"1234\", \"address\": \"1234 street\"}"
```

But I get an error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/python_test/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(data['employee_id'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I checked the type for data and it returns a str. I thought that json.loads was suppose to convert the json string into a python dict?

Comment: `event_data` is a string, which means that your JSON-data is wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`event_data` is doubly-encoded for some reason, so you need to decode it twice.

```
data = json.loads(json.loads(event_data))
```